# [ros2_control] Is it bad practice to cascade controllers?

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Would it be bad practice to cascade controllers using ros2_control?

For instance, if you had a legged robot, you may have a low level controller to command joint positions, and a higher level limb trajectory controller, and maybe an even higher level robot body controller.

```
+-----------------+             +-----------------+              +------------------+
| body controller | ----------->| limb controller | -----------> | joint controller | 
+-----------------+             +-----------------+              +------------------+
```

Would it be reasonable to have each of these controllers as separate ros2_controller interfaces, publishing updates to each other?

Or would the additional publish-subscribe interfaces add to the control latency/jitter, and would it instead be preferable to write a single node that does all 3?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/384803/%5Bros2_control%5D-is-it-bad-practice-to-cascade-controllers?/) by [shonigmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/69938/shonigmann/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1567 on 2021-08-20

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-08-22**:
No, I wouldn't call that *bad practice*. But without a real-time / deterministic OS, together with an RT capable/compatible RMW *and* RT capable/compatible controllers, it's likely this setup will -- with the current state of `ros2_control` -- introduce jitter and delays.

*Ideally* however, the setup you describe is how it all could be done. And IIRC, is also one of the goals of `ros2_control`. It's just that right now, the state of things like ROS 2's executors and a bunch of other parts of the infrastructure make this infeasible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

(Adding an answer to summarize @gvdhoorn's response and some more recent context, to close this question out prior to the stack overflow migration)

Original response from @gvdhoorn:

> No, I wouldn't call that bad practice. But without a real-time / deterministic OS, together with an RT capable/compatible RMW and RT capable/compatible controllers, it's likely this setup will -- with the current state of ros2_control -- introduce jitter and delays.
> Ideally however, the setup you describe is how it all could be done. And IIRC, is also one of the goals of ros2_control. It's just that right now, the state of things like ROS 2's executors and a bunch of other parts of the infrastructure make this infeasible.

Update:
`ros2_control` has since added support for chained controllers, [as documented here](https://github.com/ros-controls/ros2_control/blob/036640fe100fc9b5bb112a222618425db1cfd933/controller_manager/doc/controller_chaining.rst), although I'll admit I'm unaware of any potential performance ramifications.

---

Originally posted by [shonigmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/69938/shonigmann/) with karma: 1567 on 2023-08-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0